# (Single Lane Bridge problem) Allow more than one cars to cross at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency, queue

I want to have more than one threads using the same resource.

I am working on a variation of the `Single lane bridge problem` where up to three cars can cross the bridge at the same time as long as they exit the bridge in the order they entered it and as long as all of them are travelling towards the same direction.

In my version, I want up to `n` threads to have access to the common resource.

And I want each of these threads to finish calculations in the right order in a `FIFO` like way.

Is there a way to add a `Queue` of size `n` that will represent the Bridge,
and then add up to `n` treads to it?

This is my working code up till this point.

The way it is now, the left car crosses the bridge first and then the right one.

```
from threading import Lock, Thread, Semaphore
import logging
import time


class ThreadsProcessing:

    def __init__(self):
        # Threads list.
        self.threads = []
        # Lock objects.
        self.lock_enter_bridge = Lock()
        self.lock_exit_bridge = Lock()
        self.bridge_sem = Semaphore(0)


    def left_side_car(self):
        print('Car from left side is starting ...')
        print('Car from left is waiting to acquire permission to enter bridge.')
        self.lock_enter_bridge.acquire()
        print('Car from left has acquired permission to enter bridge, crossing bridge...')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Car from left is waiting to acquire lock to exit bridge.')
        self.lock_exit_bridge.acquire()
        print('Car from left has acquired lock to exit bridge')
        print('Car from left has exited the bridge and will release both locks.')
        self.lock_enter_bridge.release()
        self.lock_exit_bridge.release()
        print("Car from left tells the semaphore to the bridge semaphore that its finished with crossing the bridge")
        self.bridge_sem.release()



    def right_side_car(self):
        logging.info('Car from right side is starting ...')
        logging.info('Car from right is waiting to acquire permission to enter bridge.')
        # Two workers, wait for both of them
        numOfWorkers = 2
        for _ in range(numOfWorkers):
            print('Waiting for bridge semaphore...')
            self.bridge_sem.acquire()
            print("Car from right got the bridge semaphore")
        logging.info("Car from right is crossing the bridge...")
        time.sleep(4)
        print("Car from right has finished crossing the bridge all done")
        self.bridge_sem.release()

    def start_car_threads(self):
        for thread_func in [self.left_side_car, self.right_side_car]:
            self.threads.append(Thread(target=thread_func))
            self.threads[-1].start()

    def join_threads(self):
        for thread in self.threads:
            thread.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    car_threads = ThreadsProcessing()
    car_threads.start_car_threads()
    car_threads.join_threads()
    logging.info('Finished')
```

The full description of the problem is this:
A single lane bridge can support up to three cars that move towards the same direction. Provide an implementation that is starvation free.

i) Each car starts moving towards the left edge of the bridge(L), or the right edge(R), depending on the direction value of the Car

ii)Each car needs a random time `t_arrive` to cross the bridge.

iii)Upon the arrival of the car on the left(L) or right(R) edge of the bridge the necessary process will call the method arrive_bridge with the necessary parameters

[bridge-crossing-schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwejK.png)

Comment: Up to three cars can cross the bridge at the same time

Comment: Updated the description